# adding group with usergroup in Debian 10 doesn't seem to work

Tags: linux, usergroups

I'm trying to add a user to a group but it doesn't seem to work:

```
sudo usermod -a -G wireshark nicolas
```

But when I check my id, I get

```
uid=1000(nicolas) gid=1000(nicolas) groupes=1000(nicolas),24(cdrom),25(floppy),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev),112(bluetooth),115(scanner)
```

Or, simplier, groups

```
nicolas cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev bluetooth scanner
```

I checked that wireshark group existed with

```
$ sudo groupadd wireshark
groupadd: group 'wireshark' already exists
```

Has anyone got an idea?
Thanks

Comment: It might just be a case that you have to log out and log back in again to see the changes. Assuming you're running the command as the user you're changing.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, it worked when logging back.

Comment: No worries. I'll add my comment as an answer so you can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're currently logged in as the user you're modifying, make sure to log out and log back in again to see your updates.

For what it's worth, in the terminal you can also "switch" user to the same user with `su <username>`. (Although, that effectively nests a new login inside your current session, so if you `exit` you'll end up in your original, unmodified, session.)

[More details on Unix Stack Exchange.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96351)